# DirectorySearcher.Filter which queries active directory to return upcoming events of the current week

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to get all birthdays and anniversaries which fall under current week. I am using `Directory Searcher` and `LDAP`. I am new to `LDAP` and I am using the below code:

```
            string _path = "LDAP:";
            System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry entry = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(_path);
            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

            string month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();

            string day = DateTime.Today.Day + numDays.ToString();

             ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(description=" + month + "\\" + day +"))";
             SortOption option = new SortOption("description", System.DirectoryServices.SortDirection.Ascending);
             ds.Sort = option;
             DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
             DataTable dTable = new DataTable("Events");
             dTable.Columns.Add("birthday");
             foreach (System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult resEvent in ds.FindAll())
             {
                 System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry de1 = resEvent.GetDirectoryEntry();
                 DataRow dRow = dTable.NewRow();
                 if (de1.Properties["description"].Value != null)
                 {
                     dRow["birthday"] = de1.Properties["description"].Value.ToString();

                     dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);

                 }
             }

             dSet.Tables.Add(dTable);
             return dSet;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are your events stored under the user's description attribute?

Not much detailas to what your attribute values look like.

You are trying to user c# which I do not have access to, but from a LDAP Query, this works:
(&(objectClass=user)(description=09/15*))

-jim